# PHP - Virtuemart 2.X and Joomla 2.5x - New Virtuemart Table Structure

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have written an extension for Virtuemart 1.1.9 which retrieves products from the virtuemart database. This primarily uses the '#__vm_product" table.

Now that I have started to write a Virtuemart 2.x compatible version I have some questions.

I have noticed that my product table containing the product names is in "#__virtuemart_producs_en_gb"

I am assuming that virtuemart has detected my language during install, and created these tables with the "en_gb" suffix automatically.

My questions are:

What is the best way to detect what the suffix is likely to be on these product tables, as I am assuming that the suffix could be anything in theory, "en_us" for example, or "fr"?

Is there a config value I can search for which contains this language setting?

Any ideas about the best way to tackle this issue?

Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this may be a way of doing it...

```
$query="SELECT lang_code FROM #__languages";
$db->setQuery($query);
$lang_code = $db->loadResult();
$lang_code = strtolower(strtr($lang_code,'-','_'));

//this will fetch "EN-GB" from the database, and change it to "en_gb"
```

any thoughts on its reliability?